# How do I prevent re-renderizations for every state update in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

given this simple example,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  console.log("Component rerendered");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;`
```

I want this component to re render when Count equals X number.

The problem at hand, is a component that has hundreds of re-renders due to necesary state updates. I wish to have a better control of this re-renderizations due to performance isssues.

Comment: Given that changing the state changes what should be rendered, why would you _want_ to stop that happening. React already batches updates when the state changes frequently (hence functional updates - https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to track the count with a ref from [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const countRef = React.useRef(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    countRef.current += 1;
    
    if(countRef.current % 10 === 0) {
      setCount(countRef.current);
    }
  };

  console.log("Component rerendered");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<Counter />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

function Counter() {
  let temp = 0;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(temp);
  let X = 5;
  const handleClick = () => {
    temp++;
    if (temp == X) {
      setCount(temp);
    }
  };

  console.log('Component rerendered');
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Assuming that your X number is 5

Comment: This is dangerous - component could re-render for a reason unrelated to count state and rest counter `temp`.

Comment: But I have check, component only updating when state is updating and state is updating when counter is equal to x number.

Comment: Component can re-render, because parent has re-rendered, his state or context changed